# "File Copying" section in K&R

Tags: c, getchar, kernighan-and-ritchie

I'm new to programming and I can't seem to get my head around why the following happens in my code, which is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*copy input to output; 1st version */

main()
{
    int c;

c = getchar();
while (c != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
    }
}
```

So after doing some reading, I've gathered the following:

1. Nothing executes until I hit Enter as `getchar()` is a holding function.
2. Before I hit Enter, all my keystrokes are stored in a buffer
3. When `getchar()` is called upon, it simply goes looks at the first value in the buffer, becomes that value, and then removes that value from the buffer.

My question is that when I remove the first `c = getchar()` the resulting piece of code has exactly the same functionality as the original code, albeit before I type anything a smiley face symbol immediately appears on the screen. Why does this happen? Is it because `putchar(c)` doesn't hold up the code, and tries to display `c`, which isn't yet defined, hence it outputs some random symbol? I'm using Code::Blocks if that helps.

Comment: If you remove the first `getchar`, the program has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you listed will simply echo back to you every character you type at it. It is true that the I/O is "buffered". It is the keyboard input driver of the operating system that is doing this buffering. While it's buffering keys you press, it echoes each key back at you. When you press a newline the driver passes the buffered characters along to your program and `getchar` then sees them.

As written, the function should work fine:

```
c = getchar();   // get (buffer) the first char

while (c != EOF) {  // while the user has not typed ^D (EOF)
    putchar(c);     // put the character retrieved
    c = getchar();  // get the next character
}
```

Because of the keyboard driver buffering, it will only echo back every time you press a newline or you exit with ^D (EOF).

The smiley face is coming from what @YuHao described: you might be missing the first `getchar` in what you ran, so `putchar` is echoing junk. Probably a 0, which looks like a smiley on your screen.

Comment: Yeah, still not very clear why not just swap ```c = getchar();``` and ```putchar(c);``` inside the loop and throw away the first c declaration? Just checked and it seems like junk disappears from the output. I don't understand what is undefined in that case?

Comment: @user3081519 by "the first c declaration" do you mean "the first c assignment"? You could refactor this loop a little, but if you get rid of the first assignment, then the first `while` check for `c != EOF` becomes meaningless, and you stand the chance of attempting to `putchar(c)` when `c` is `EOF`. You have to ask yourself: What if the first read of `c` is already EOF, for example? The loop could be rewritten as a `for` loop: `for ( c = getchar(); c != EOF; c = getchar() ) putchar(c);`.

Comment: Ohh! I see. So with my version it would still implicitly run once in case of EOF which is probably the very definition of being a bug. That's enlightening, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you ommit the first `getchar()`, the code will look like this:

```
int c;
while (c != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
}
```

Here, `c` is uninitialized, so calling `putchar(c)` the first time will output a garbage value, that's where you get the smiley face.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm new to programming"

You're not advised to learn programming using C (and the difficulties you're going through are because of the C language). For example, my first computer science classes were in pascal. Other univesities may use scheme or lisp, or even structured natural languages to teach programming. MIT's online classes are given in python.

C is not a language you would want to use in the first months of programming. The specific reason in your case is due to the fact that the language allowed you to use the value of an uninitialized value.

When you declare the integer variable "c", it gets an implicitly reserved space on the program stack, but without have any meaningful value: it's "trash", the value is whatever value was already on memory at that time. The C language requires that the programmer implicitly knows that he needs to assign some value before using a variable. Removing the first getchar results in uses before assignment in the while condition (c != EOF) and putchar(c), both before c has any meaningful value.

Consider the same code rewritten in python:

```
import sys

c = sys.stdin.read(1)
while c != '':
    c = sys.stdin.read(1)
    sys.stdout.write(c)
```

Remove the initial read and you get the following error:

```
hdante@aielwaste:/tmp$ python3 1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 3, in <module>
    while c != '':
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
```

That's a NameError: you used the value without assigned to it resulted in a language error.

For more information, try an online course, for example:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/video-lectures/

About uninitialized values:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable